# Move files from S3 to AWS EFS on the fly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, amazon-efs

I am building an application where the user can upload images, for this I am using S3 as files storage.

In other area of the application there is some process deployed on EC2 that need to use the uploaded images.
This process need the images multiple times (it generate some report with it) and it's in part of multiple EC2 - using elastic beanstalk.

The process doesn't need all the images at once, but need some subset of it every job it gets (depend the parameters it gets).

Every ec2 instance is doing an independent job - they are not sharing file between them but they might need the same uploaded images.

What I am doing now is to download all the images from s3 to the EC2 machine because it's need the files locally.
I have read that EFS can be mounted to an EC2 and then I can access it like it was a local storage.

I did not found any example of uploading directly to EFS with nodejs (or other lang) but I found a way to transfer file from S3 to EFS - "DataSync".
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/transfer-data-to-efs.html

So I have 3 questions about it:

1. It is true that I can't upload directly to EFS from my application? (nodesjs + express)
2. After I move files to EFS, will I able to use it exactly like it in the local storage of the ec2?
3. Is it a good idea to move file from s3 to efs all the time or there is other solution to the problem I described?

Comment: Can you tell us more about "some process deployed on EC2 that need to use the uploaded images"? Are you saying that it needs ALL uploaded images? Does it _always_ need access to every image, or does it only require it once, after the initial upload? Do you have _multiple_ EC2 instances, or just one instance? Please tell us as much as you can about your system so that we can give you a good answer.

Comment: I added more explanation about the EC2 process. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Amazon EFS is a filesystem that can be mounted on multiple Amazon EC2 instances. If you require shared storage between multiple instances, then it is a good medium to use. If you are only using S3 as a place to upload files, then it would be feasible to store the images on EFS instead of S3. Moving an image from S3 to EFS would be easiest if done by your app running on EC2, since it can access both S3 (via API calls) and EFS (as a mounted filesystem). Alternatively, you could use S3 as the main storage and the app would download required images from S3 when it needs them.

Comment: Dear AWS. I have the same use case 

Answer (score 0):

For this exact situation, we use https://github.com/kahing/goofys

It's very reliable, and additionally, offers the ability to mount S3 buckets as folders on any device - windows, mac as well as of course Linux.

Works outside of the AWS cloud 'boundary' too - great for developer laptops.

Downside is that it does /not/ work in a Lambda context, but you can't have everything!

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a Lambda to call an ECS task when the file is uploaded to s3. The ECS task starts and mounts the EFS volume and copies the file from s3 to the EFS.
This wont run into problems with really large files with Lambda getting timed out.
I dont have the code but would be interested if someone already has this solution coded.